# При выходе за определённый квадрат на экране не рисуются точки, как в opengl установить масштаб 1:1 к пикселям

Tags: c++, opengl

Написал процедуру, она рисует точки, но при выходе за определённый квадрат на экране - не рисует.  Пытался менять конфигурацию opengl - не получается.

```
void OnMouseMove(int x, int y){
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
glVertex2i(x,y);
glEnd();
glFlush();
SwapBuffers(hDC);
}
```

Конфигурация

```
void Render(){
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glScalef(1,1,0);
glViewport(0,0,400,300); // Окно 400px x 300 px
glFlush();
SwapBuffers(hDC);
}
```

Comment: И что это за *определенный квадрат*?

Comment: Как вы настраивается матрицу проекции? Приложите пожалуйста скриншот. Скорее всего вызвать вот так glVertex2i(x,y); не имеет смысла, т.к. x,y - это координаты экрана, а в функцию glVertex2i вы должны передавать координаты мира. Можете например прочитать вот эту статью http://100byte.ru/100btwrks/prjctn/prjctn.html

Comment: Я не знаю как настроить её, сейчас рисует только в верхнем правом углу. Как-то добивался сдвига влево - и получал всёравно что левая часть экрана закрашивается а правая нет. Добится что б где клик там точка - не получилось. Ссылку спасибо, почитаю, сложно найти где нормально написана настройка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glViewport (0, 0, 400, 300); // область вывода
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // активная матрица - проекция
glLoadIdentity();                    // делаем активную матрицу единичной
gluOrtho2D(0,400,0,300);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // активная матрица - модельвью
glLoadIdentity();                    // делаем активную матрицу единичной
glScalef( 1, 1, 1 );  // домножаем! активную матрицу на масштаб
```

После этого координаты работают в масштабе 1:1 с пикселями.